# Migration failed with source plugin exception

Tags: 7, database, migrations

I'm getting the following error:

```
Migration failed with source plugin exception Migration failed with source plugin exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'posmsoftllc' for column 'sourceid1' at row 1
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

It has something to do with my MigrateSQLMap - there's no real primary key on the source database, but I suppose username would probably work. I've got the MigrateSQLMap setup as follows:

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, array(
  'Username' => array('type' => 'varchar',
    'length' => 75,
    'unsigned' => FALSE,
    'not null' => FALSE,
  )
    ), MigrateDestinationEntityAPI::getKeySchema('commerce_line_item', 'recurring')
);
```

But I'm receiving this error - what could be causing this? Why is it expecting an integer value? Do I even need this map for a successful migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find when I get these errors it is because initially I make an sqlmap using an integer key -- then see I don't have an integer key and try to change it. The migration still expects the *initial* configuration of an int key. You likely have to clear it out as seen in this [issue comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1105652#comment-4404064).

> Everything looks OK to me. Is it possible that when you initially
>   defined your migration, you had an integer key in the MigrateSQLMap
>   call? Changing the key in the code will not automatically change the
>   associated tables. What you can do is:
>
> 1. Rollback the AttSubject migration, so the map and message tables are
>      empty.
> 2. Drop the migrate_map_attsubject and migrate_message_attsubject
>      tables.
> 3. Run "drush ms". This should call the ensureTables() method and
>      recreate the map and message tables using your ca_varchar1 key schema.
> 4. Check the structure of the map and message tables and make sure
>      sourceid1 is a varchar in both.

Also see this [issue which describes the same problem](https://www.drupal.org/node/2044987#comment-7664151) and solution with more examples/details.

Comment: Ah, yes, I initially did have it set as an INT field.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander ya migrate is realllly powerful, but it has tiny gotchas like this that can drive you crazy :) kudos on your success!